# Double special characters on windows US-international keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, special-characters

I use the US-international layout on windows 10 to be able to write accents, `ñ` or `¿`(Spanish), but whenever I want to write some standard special characters (not all), like `^`, `~`, `` ` ``, `'` or `"` , I need to press `shift+key+key`, generating two characters instead of one, and I can't find a way to generate the character only once, so I always have to delete the extra character that is generated every time I need to use them. For example :

(now) `shift+6+6` outputs `^^`, but `shift+6` doesn't output any character

(I would like to) `shift+6` outputs `^`

Maybe it's unavoidable in this keyboard layout, but **is there a way to get `shift+key` to output the character I need? Is there another distribution that can do this and still allow me to use `ñ` or `¿` ?**

ps: I used a keyboard with the US layout for many years, so I would like to continue using the same key layout

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it depends on what character follows the up-caret, ^. With a vowel that takes a diacritic, e.g.,<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, you get the accented character **ô**. With other characters, you get the up-caret and then the letter, e.g., <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, produces just **^**, as desired. Hit <kbd>Space</kbd> after a "dead key" to get the original character.

Second, if you have *both* US and International US English keyboards installed, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to immediately switch between the two layouts. *Voilà*, pardon my accent.

Comment: Perfect, that solves the problem, thank you very much! I had thought that the double character could be related to some special characters, but until now I didn't know how to avoid it.